# jquery form value lookup from other element

Tags: jquery, xhtml

I have a form which has two elements, a selection box and an input field. I have a JQuery autocomplete action on the input field that fetches a list of usernames from a remote datasource.

I would like to make the lookup more flexible and use the selection box as my selector for the data type fetched in the input field.

Both the Selection box and input field are under the ID = obj1, how do i reference the value of the selection box within the $.ajax > data option

Comment: please post your code ... and you can't have two elements with the same id!

Comment: Any chance you can post your code?

Comment: scibuff you may have aanswered it for me, I think i need to use different ID's

Answer (score 0):

$('select#obj1').val()

Simple as that. 
For the input you do this $('input#obj1').val()

Comment: How do i make that more flexible with multiple items on the page e.g. obj2, object3 all using the same code